# problem with symfony module security using remote editing

Tags: security, symfony1

i'm working in a large php project using the Symfony framework. 
Context:
My computer's OS is Windows and i have no admin rights, so i can't install anything. Thats why i use a remote folder in a linux computer using WinSCP, sincornizing my windows project folder with the linux project folder in the other computer.

Problem:
Editing the security.yml file of an specific module, strange things happens: sometimes, security is ignored. When i activate global security uses to work correctly, but when i desactivate it, seems like global security is still active :S

Code

```
`
private:
  is_secure:   on
  credentials: admin
all:
  is_secure:   off

`
```

i have this file sotred on /apps/frontend_dev/modules/modulex/config/security.yml

Maybe is a syncronization problem, or because of the Symfony caché system

Thanks :)

Comment: with global security i mean security at application level

Comment: I would say it's the cache - run the clear cache command (or just empty the cache folder) after changing these files - or use the dev front controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the cache and overwitting the security.yml files of each app, the probel was solved. Maybe not a solution but it worked to me :D